# pymssql - SELECT works but UPDATE doesn't

Tags: pymssql

[image]

```
import pymssql
import decimal

CONN = pymssql.connect(server='1233123123', user='s123', password='sa1231231', database='DBforTEST')
CURSOR = CONN.cursor()
"""it is good code. here is no problem"""
CURSOR.execute("SELECT ttt from test where w=2")
ROW = CURSOR.fetchone()
tmp = list()
tmp.append(ROW)
if ROW is None:
    print("table has nothing")
else:
    while ROW:
        ROW = CURSOR.fetchone()
        tmp.append(ROW)
print(tmp)
"""it works!"""

CURSOR.execute("""
                UPDATE test 
                SET 
                w = 16
                where ttt = 1
                """)
"it doesnt works"
```

I'm using python 3.5 with pymssql.

In my code, `SELECT` state works, so I can guarantee the connection is perfect.
But the `UPDATE` state doesn't work in Python.
The same code works in SSMS.

What is the problem?
I guess `SELECT` state is only for read, so DB can provide Data, but `UPDATE` is modifying DB, so DB blocks it.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CONN.commit()
```

if autocommit is not set then you have to commit yourself.